# I Wrote This HTML Code with Javascript Functions and Validations..but the Validation doesn't work, what am i doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation

This is the Code I Wrote but the Javascript Validation is not working..is the syntax wrong...this is a past paper question.
The Program Contains a HTML Form and a Javascript Function with a validation
The Validations are that The Username shouldn't be empty and the Telephone Textbox should be numeric

**Javascript Function**

```
function val(this)
{
  if(document.Regal.UName.value.length==0)
  {
    alert("UserName Empty");
    return false;
  }
  if (isNaN(document.valid.TeleNO.value))
  {
    prompt("Telephone Empty");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form="Regal">
<h1><b>Regal Real Estate Agency</b></h1><br>
<h2><b><u>Property Inspection Request Form</u></b></h2><br>
Name:
  <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
Telephone:
  <input type="text" name="Telephone"><br>
Reference Code:
  <input type="text" name="RC"><br>
Select Site To Vist
  <select name="Select Site">
  <option value ="Select Site"checked="checked">Select Site</option>
  <option value ="Colombo">Colombo</option>
  <option value ="Gampha">Gampha</option>
  <option value ="Galle">Galle</option>
  </select>
  When Is It Convient For Us To Contact You To Make An Appointment?
  <input type="radio" name="appointment" value="Morning" checked="true">
  <input type="radio" name="appointment" value="Afternoon">
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="SendInfo" value="Send" onclick="return val()"/> <br><br>
  <input type="button" name="SendInfo" value="Cancel"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please describe what the code is supposed to do

Comment: @shofstetter The Username shouldn't be empty and the Telephone Textbox should be numeric

Comment: As @schofsetter mentions you need to explain what you are expecting to happen, what actually happens, and what you have tried. SO is not just for people to fix your code.

Comment: @theo I know that, i'm just asking what have i done wrong..i did everything according to my HTML book but the javascript function doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You seem to have posted an incomplete snippet, does your file really start `function val(this)`? If so this may be part of your problem - you are missing  `<html>`, `<head>` and `<script>` tags.

Comment: @theo Ah no, i kinda removed the html,head and script tags for this question here..its actually in my code.

Comment: @AshanCabral Just trying to help you make your question better. You will get better answers this way. You say its not working, but don't mention what actually happens. Does the form just submit even though the values are bad? Do you get any Javascript errors? *If you are not familiar with the javascript console, you should learn about this first as it can point you directly at problems; slightly different depending on browser but see the [chrome docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) to get you started.*

Comment: @theo Unfortunately i didnt get any errors but thanks for your time
i will try to find a way to fix this.

Comment: @theo I Tried The Code You Gave Me
IT WORKED!
Thanks Man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For form validation you should use the onsubmit event of the form.

This page includes some examples that should help you:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I Will Try This and Let You Know